# Name object in Scala List constructor

Tags: list, scala

Given two classes A() and B(a: A) I want to use them to construct a List like this:

`List(val a = A(), B(a))`

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare a val when calling the List constructor like that. Assuming that A and B are case classes, splitting your example into two lines like this:

```
val a = A()
List(a, B(a))
```

should have the effect you want.

If the goal is to reduce the scope of `a`, you can do something like this:

```
val l = {
   val a = A()
   List(a, B(a))
}
```

and `a` will not be visible outside of the definition of `l`.

Comment: Yeah I know that. I just thought there is the way. Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I've edited to include a suggestion if you're trying to keep the scope a is visible in to a minimum.

Comment: It is exactly what I needed, to limit the scope. I forgot about this syntax :) Not as short as I wanted though. Thanks a lot!